# Eclipse android, exception when using database in fragment listview

Tags: android, database, eclipse, listview, android-fragments

I've been looking for hours now and I still get the same error message.
I'm new to eclipse and would be gratefull if anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

I'm making a small project where I can get a listview with games. I can sort these in a wishlist or an already played list.

In this fragment I want to show a simple listview with the game titles in. Everytime I try to open the fragment, the app crashes and gives the following errors :

> 08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253): Process:
>   be.thomasmore.GameLab_2, PID: 2253 08-09 16:15:10.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2253): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{be.thomasmore.GameLab_2/be.thomasmore.GameLab_2.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 08-09 16:15:10.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 08-09
>   16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 08-09
>   16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 08-09 16:15:10.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 08-09
>   16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-09
>   16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 08-09 16:15:10.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 08-09
>   16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-09 16:15:10.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2253): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   be.thomasmore.GameLab_2.DatabaseHelper.getSpellen(DatabaseHelper.java:223)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   be.thomasmore.GameLab_2.GameFragmentTab.readSpellen(GameFragmentTab.java:57)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   be.thomasmore.GameLab_2.GameFragmentTab.onCreateView(GameFragmentTab.java:36)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 08-09
>   16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):     at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 08-09
>   16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):     at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240) 08-09
>   16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
>   08-09 16:15:10.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2253):   ... 11 more

So here is my Fragment :

> > public class GameFragmentTab extends Fragment {
>
> ```
>   private DatabaseHelper db;
>
>
>
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activitygame_layout, container, false);
>     return rootView;
>
>
> }
>
> @Override     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>   db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
>
>   readSpellen();  }
>
> private void readSpellen() {
>     final List<Spel> spellen = db.getSpellen();
>
>
>     ArrayAdapter<Spel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Spel>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,spellen);
>
>
>     final ListView listViewSpellen = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewSpellen);
>     listViewSpellen.setAdapter(adapter);
>
>    }
> ```

And this is a part of the DatabaseHelper I created where I create getSpellen()  ( getGames) . I know this normally works since I made the same project without fragments.

> public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
>       // Database Version
>       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
>       // Database Name
>       private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "games";
>
> ```
> // uitgevoerd bij instantiatie van DatabaseHelper
> // -> als database nog niet bestaat, dan creÎren (call onCreate) 
> // -> als de DATABASE_VERSION hoger is dan de huidige versie, 
> //    dan upgraden (call onUpgrade) 
> public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
>     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
> }
> ```
>
> @Override   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
>
> ```
>           //spel          String CREATE_TABLE_SPEL = "CREATE TABLE spel (" +
>             "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
>             "naam TEXT," +
>             "jaar INTEGER," +
>             "hoofdpersonage TEXT," +
>             "leeftijdsklasse TEXT," +
>             "ratingbeschrijving TEXT," +
>             "rating TEXT," +
>             "studioId INTEGER," +
>             "genreId INTEGER," +
>             "platformId INTEGER)";
>
>
>     db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SPEL);
> ```
>
> public List getSpellen() {
>           List lijst = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
>     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM spel ORDER BY naam";
>
>     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
>     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
>
>     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
>         do {
>             Spel spel = new Spel(cursor.getLong(0),
>                     cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),
> ```
>
> cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),
>   cursor.getInt(6),cursor.getInt(7),cursor.getInt(8),cursor.getInt(9));
>                   lijst.add(spel);
>               } while (cursor.moveToNext());
>           }
>
> ```
>     cursor.close();
>     db.close();
>     return lijst;
> }
> ```

Ofcourse I also inserted some games.
I'm sorry if this question isn't 100%, it's my first question I have ever posted.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello the log-cat is a bit missing. When posting the error there should a place where it says Caused By... This is actually where the error really is and on click of this line it would take you a specific line in the code. This would help us figure out the issue

Comment: The Caused by I found is :  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
However, when I try to double click something in logcat, nothing is happening.. is my eclipse broken? Since I have had some issues in the past already

Comment: I do not want you to double click please continue the Caused by : Null PointerException at ... and by the towards end it should show : (Class Name: certain number ). Please post the whole thing

Comment: 08-09 19:33:13.607: E/AndroidRuntime(1277): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 19:33:13.607: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):  at be.thomasmore.GameLab_2.GameFragmentTab.readSpellen(GameFragmentTab.java:201)

Comment: Okay great. Now when you click (just one on the GrameFragmentTab. java : 201) where does that refer to in the code? copy past the line of the code

Comment: It goes to the function :  private void readSpellen() {
     
     final List<Spel> spellen = db.getSpellen();

        
        ArrayAdapter<Spel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Spel>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,spellen);
        
        
        final ListView listViewSpellen = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewSpellen);
        listViewSpellen.setAdapter(adapter);

}

-
-
and the specific line it refers too is : 

-
-
-
-
listViewSpellen.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Okay I will post an answer and we will start fixing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the listview is null because you are not accessing it from onCreateView as if not refering to it from the xml, so :

```
public class GameFragmentTab extends Fragment {
 private DatabaseHelper db;
  final ListView listViewSpellen;
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activitygame_layout, container, false);
 listViewSpellen = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewSpellen);
db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

 readSpellen();  }

private void readSpellen() {
final List<Spel> spellen = db.getSpellen();


ArrayAdapter<Spel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Spel>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,spellen);

listViewSpellen.setAdapter(adapter);
return rootView;
}
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error. 
I maybe thought it had something to do with the database.. But when I do the exact same thing in a normal activity, and not a fragment, everything works fine. Did I forget a specific line or something?

Do I maybe need to use onActivitycreated? I'm new too fragments, so I'm not really sure what too use.

Comment: Then the adapter is null. Please check my edited answer

Comment: Yes! It works now! So you don't actually need an OnCreate function?
But thank you very, very much!

Comment: @Elijenta please accept the answer if this solution works for you so that others can benefit. In addition, in fragments onCreateView acts as onCreate. I am always ready to help. Happy coding